# How to get a specified Cookie path using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Is there anyway to get a specified cookie's path in Javascript?

I have a javascript method which will return a cookie value based on its name. Is it possible to add a filter to the method so that it will fetch cookies from particular paths only?

My requirement is to fetch cookies from a path named `/ctp`

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: please read the documentation for cookies -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: i don't think cookies that are out of path should even show up...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`cookies.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll), which requires setting up a [`manifest.webmanifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) file and there's [caveats](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/issues/194#issuecomment-338422836) among support issues.

Personally I think `localStorage` and/or `sessionStorage` are a far better choice... well if keeping one's sanity is an option, otherwise best of luck keeping values *fresh* across objects reading and writing data.